# Need help troubleshooting with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a HashMap which I initialize once in static block from a json file. Then I work with my local HashMap to save users requests.

```
static {
  TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
  MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(ConcurrentHashMap.class, String.class, GooglePlayGame.class);
  try {
       games = mapper.readValue(new File("games.json"), mapType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

When I decide to stop app and launch it again, I can add new pair of "key-value" to this map, but when I'm trying to append changes into my json file, everything that was already in json file is duplicated + new value.
This code:

```
try(JsonGenerator g = mapper.getFactory().createGenerator(
                  new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("games.json"), true))))) {
    mapper.writeValue(g, games);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I understood why it's happening (because of static initialization every new launch, and then I write to file all hashmap again and again), but I don't know how to fix this. I want to append new pairs to existing json file.

For example:
Adding first request, all fine:

```
{"Machinarium":
   {"Title":"Machinarium",
    "Updated":"28 February, 2019",
    "Version":"2.5.6","Requirements":"4.1,
     "Contacts":"support@amanita-design.net"
}
```

Then I restart app and got another request, my json file now looks like:

```
{"Machinarium":
   {"Title":"Machinarium",
    "Updated":"28 February, 2019",
    "Version":"2.5.6","Requirements":"4.1,
     "Contacts":"support@amanita-design.net",
....
},
{"Machinarium":
   {"Title":"Machinarium",
    "Updated":"28 February, 2019",
    "Version":"2.5.6","Requirements":"4.1,
     "Contacts":"support@amanita-design.net",
....
},
"Samorost 3":
   {"Title":"Samorost 3",
    "Updated":"November 14, 2019",
     "Version":"1.0",
     "Requirements":"4.3,
...}
```

As you can see, duplicate here.

So the goal is: create HashMap -> get user request -> write this request(pair "key-value") to local hashmap -> write hashmap (or every pair separately? hmm) to json file. Then when app starts again: initialize hashmap from this json file with saved requests -> get new user request -> add new requests to json file.

I need to write each pair one by one to file (not all map), but how?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're looking for. Is it simply that you don't want duplicates for the same primary key? What about the case where data in those with the same key (e.g. `Machinarium`) have different contents, (e.g. `Version`)?

Comment: No, in this case I will probably just rewrite old value in HashMap. Maybe will found other solution later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, your issue is here: `new FileWriter(new File("games.json"), true))`.

The `FileWriter` constructor is `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` so you are appending data to that file every time you write.

What you want instead is just `FileWriter(File file)` which overwrites the file by default. This assumes that your `games` map is always up to date and has all the data in memory.

This is a bit less efficient since you'd be overwriting the entire file every time a change is made, but this doesn't seem likely to be a lot of data, so I don't think it should be a concern. If this turns out to be a very large amount of data that is updated frequently, you may want to look into using a database instead of a JSON file.

Comment: Yeap, I was thinking about it - just rewrite all file. Get new pair, then rewrite all HashMap into new file. Just wanted to find out better solution. :)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a better solution. It's a pretty simple storage system. The alternative is to use some sort of embedded database like SQLite if you want to do in place updates, which is probably a better solution if you want to ensure data consistency. If you don't want SQL, you can look into an embedded NoSQL database, but I've never used any of those.